# Good Game Development Libraries for Java

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm going to be taking a class on Java soon, and I'm probably going to have a lot of free time during the class for the first few weeks. I figured that I would mess around with game design in my free time and was wondering if anyone could recommend some Java libraries that are good for game development.

Thanks.

Comment: A good answer is likely to depend on what kind of game you want to write (a card game will require a different engine than an ego shooter, you know ...)

Comment: or put differently: Do you need realtime interaction? Are graphics 2D or 3D? Do you need a physics engine? Pathfinding? Networking? Sound? ...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/). It's an easy-to-use comprehensive 2D game library: a great platform for experimenting with Java.

Since you don't have any experience with Java yet, I would advise you stay clear of low-level libraries such as LWJGL or complex libraries such as JMonkeyEngine.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't youtube channel from my answer your? :)

Comment: Slick2D has no real improvements during the last time. I would rather use libgdx.

Comment: You can use SDL also quit easy.

Comment: Slick2D is deprecated. LibGDX is the better option these days. http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend you: [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org)

This guys tutorials can help you a lot: http://www.youtube.com/user/TheCodingUniverse

He is explaining how to make games using LWJGL in detail.

Also, have a look at: [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

Answer (score 4):

[JME](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) is a platform worth looking at.