# Which java class should I use for my 2D game graphics?

Tags: java

I am about to write a platform-game (like the old Super Mario), and I want to write that in Java. Which of the graphic classes is the better one to use for this purpose? I have found JFrame, Graphics, Graphics2d, JApplet etc.

The game will consist of a moving background (an image), a charachter with motions (also images), and some blocks for the level (also images). I want to be able to run it in fullscreen.

Which class should I use?

Comment: If it's 2d, I normally just recommend working with it yourself. It's once you make the move to 3d that libraries like OpenGL come in handy.

Comment: What do you mean by working it myself? How do I get the program frame if I don't use a library?

Comment: [Java's 2D graphics implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) :)

Comment: @theva Questions asking for libraries or off site resources are off topic for SO.  Read the [faq] to see how to format the question better, which will probably not end in downvotes and maybe some good answers.

Comment: You have not found "graphics libraries". You have found classes, that all do different things.

Comment: ops, my bad, I taught of classes of course, I have edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, JApplet is a kind of Java application that runs inside the browser (mostly obsolete nowadays), JFrame is a kind of window class, while Graphics and Graphics2d are mid-level graphic libraries.

If you want to use Java's built-in libraries, you really should read those tutorials in order to have a basic understanding of it:

- http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/

Alternatively, there are lots of Java game libraries out there, [you could take a look at them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344464/good-game-development-libraries-for-java)